# Copy folder in Azure Storage Account to another folder in the same storage account

Tags: azure, github-actions, azcopy

I have a Github Worfklow in which I am trying to copy all blobs in a folder to another folder in the same Azure storage account using the "az storage" command.
Ideally it should be synchronous so that Github Action must be able to track the progress.

I am not sure if "az storage" is even the correct command to use, perhaps AZCopy will be better? But I am not sure how to use AZCopy within Github actions (what should the value for "uses" be?)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
az storage copy --source-account-name name_here --source-container 'mycontainer' --source-blob 'test/*' --account-name name_here --destination-container 'mycontainer' --destination-blob test2 --recursive
```